# Connect to 9gag with HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I want to do a windows store app for 9gag. I use HttpClient

I want to connect the user so he will be able to like/unlike. So, I do a POST request to 9gag/login with the data and it fails. A coworker did a similar thing in JavaScript and it worked...

```
    private async void connect()
    {

        try
        {
            string result;

            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url + "login/");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            string key = takeKey(result);

            var values = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "csrftoken", key }, { "username", username }, { "password", password } };
            //Header of the http request
            HttpContent header = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url + "login/", header);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            string test = response.IsSuccessStatusCode.ToString();
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException hre)
        {
            string test = "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // For debugging
            string test = "";
        }

    }
```

I tried different ways to put the HTTPContent.... It's one of them...
The value of url is "http://9gag.com/", so when I put a breakpoint at the end. When I see the result and try it on a browser, i get the error : "Please try again". If the password is bad, I get the error : "Wrong combination user/password blablabla".

So, any ideas?.... I didn't find anything....

Comment: You request the response asynchronously.

Comment: Yeah, because in the .Net for Windows Store Apps everything is Async.. Before I wanted to use HttpWebRequest, for the not async methods were not available...

Comment: Yes but you request the content on a new thread and right after starting the thread, read a string that hasn't been written to yet

Comment: Ok, but I when I put a breakpoint on : response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url + "login/", header); values has the good token, and when I put a breakpoint on : string test = response.IsSuccessStatusCode.ToString();, the result strind contain in the html code the "Try Again"

I was thinking that "await" pause the thread, because when I followed the program step by step, it always takes 1 or 2 seconds to move on the next line after a postAsync or getAsync...

For now, everything I do with result is in this fonction, not in the rest of the program because I know it's async in another thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of a bug in the .Net framework, not handeling cookies very well.

If you have chrome, or firefox with the firebug plugin installed, or you have an other way to read the cookies in you're browser, I will explain.

The list of cookies you get from 9gag are most of the time meant for the domain ".9gag.com", except for 1, named ts1, this one is crucial to login, but is not for the domain ".9gag.com" but for "9gag.com", because of a bug in .Net the ts1 cookie is not stored.

Here you have a small workaround, however I am not sure if this is completely stable,

```
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie();

        cookie.Domain = "9gag.com";

        cookie.Name = "ts1";

        cookie.Value = "VALUEOFTHISCOOKIE";

        this._Cookies.Add(new Uri("http://9gag.com"), cookie);
```

In the above code you have to replace "VALUEOFTHISCOOKIE" with the value of the cookie as it is in your browser (in my case: fb221d618c89577cf59c7ce5fd300c5b43e4259f).

This worked for me, I get a 302 response code if the login is correct.